# How do I handle grub rescue mode after installing burg?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, bootloader, burg

I installed *burg* on my computer, and after restarting, grub comes up with the following message:

```
GRUB loading.
error: no such device: 9b16030c-08f8-4f5d-b228-63e13bca7839
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

typing the `ls` command will bring me this:

```
(hd0)
```

This is probably wrong, Ive seen people have many more listings when doing that command.

when I type the command `set`, it comes up with:

```
prefix=(hd0)/boot/burg
root=hd0
```

I have tried the commands:

set prefix=(hd0,x)/boot/grub
    set root=(hd0,x)
    insmod normal
    normal

I have tried pretty much every variation of that code, I do not get errors on the `set prefix` and the `set root` commands, but when I try any variation of the `Insmod` command, then it comes up with either the error `Unknown partition` or `Unknown filesystem`

Variations tried of the `insmod` command

```
Insmod (hd0,x)/boot/grub/normal.mod
```

This comes up with the `unknown partition` error

```
Insmod normal
```

This comes up with the `unknown filesystem` error

The `unknown partition` error seems to appear when `(hd0,x)/boot` is specified

I have tried booting from a cd and it doesn't seem to work.

I am dual booted with windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04
How can I recover from this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

user121839 is correct.

I had a similar issue on a system where I'd moved the partitions around, and ls listed all of my partitions, not just the drive (hd0).

For the benefit of future googlers:

Upon hitting

```
grub rescue>
```

Run `ls` to get a list of drives and partitions, for example:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2)
```

If you only see `(hd0)` then you probably need to examine the drive with another computer or a Live boot.

Run `set` to get a look at your current boot settings:

```
prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos2
```

If you have a system and a swap partition and grub is trying to boot from the swap (as with my situation), this might be the sort of issue you see.

You can use `cat` and `ls` to examine files or check for their existence:

```
ls (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/
cat (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Set the correct boot partition.  Note: I did not use `set`, just typed the environment assignments in directly (`prefix=value`).

```
set prefix=(hd0,x)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,x)
```

Then load grub to boot.

```
insmod normal
normal
```

I hope that's helpful, citizens of the future.

Answer (score 1):

> This is probably wrong, Ive seen people have many more listings when doing that command.

Yes it should at least list all the partitions on that drive.
But it looks like your disk is just empty (no partition table) or at leat GRUB can't find anything (wrong grub-configuration).
Have you tried to boot a LiveCD/USB and check your drive?

> I have tried booting from a cd and it doesn't seem to work.

If you realy can't even boot from CD/USB means the problem might be your bios settings.

Comment: THanks for the input
i think that booting from a cd and uninstalling burg might be the best option, I'll look into booting from the cd more, I haven't researched that hardly at all yet.